# PHP: Alternative to returning a blank file

Tags: php, return

In my `blank.php` it currently has following:

```
<?php
// Blank file...
```

I am using this file to replace a particular template in my WordPress like so:

```
add_filter( 'comments_template', blank_file' );
function blank_file() {
    return PLUGIN_PATH . '/blank.php';
}
```

However, instead of creating a blank file to return, is it possible to just return a blank value to get the same results? I tried the following which would make sense to me logically, but it didn't work:

```
function blank_file() {
    $blank = '<?php';
    return $blank;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar question on WordPress Stack Exchange [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/228266/98212). However, it looks like the solutions require more coding than what I am currently using which works for me:

```
add_filter( 'comments_template', 'comments_template', 20, 1 );
 function comments_template() {
    return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'blank.php';
}
```

Where `blank.php` has:

```
<?php
// Blank file...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the function `blank_file` is supposed to return a path to a blank file.

Try

```
return '/dev/null';
```

and

```
return 'data:text/plain,';
```

The second will work on not only unix if whatever uses your function supports data URI.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I tried both returns separately and both of them didn't work. Maybe I am doing something wrong? Also what do you mean by your last sentence?

Comment: What happens when you use the first way?

Comment: When I used `return '/dev/null';` the results aren't the same if I were to return the `blank.php`.

Comment: What's the difference?